# Are luxury hotel rooms in the Sydney area available at a discount during the lockdown?

Tags: budget, australia, accommodation, event-based-effects, luxury

During the current lockdown, there's a major reduction in international and inter-state travel in Australia. Is it possible to book rooms in luxury hotels, such as Shangri-La, in the Sydney area at a cheaper rate than they'd normally be offered?

I'm open to using an opaque hotel booking - I'm not interested in location, just so long as it's [noice, unusual and different](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kath_%26_Kim).

I had a quick look at Shangri-La Sydney's [offers](https://www.shangri-la.com/en/sydney/shangrila/offers/?gc=) page, but I didn't notice any specials that seemed oriented to the current couple of months (apart from the winter package, which I remember them doing in past years).

Comment: At least in Europe, I do not have the impression that the lockdown has caused cheaper travel or any bargains. People are refraining from travel, not because they can't afford to travel, but because they are not allowed or do not want to travel. Lowering the prices is not realistically going to attract new customers, but cause less income from those who are travelling anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> at a cheaper rate than they'd normally be offered?

Hard to tell. There is not really a "normal" price for hotels in urban areas any more and the prices fluctuate a lot depending a lot on supply & demand. Before the pandemic, pricing was extremely dynamic and it was not unusual to see room prices go up or down by a factor 3-4 in matter of days. One night last year a dinky Holiday Inn in the Boston area went up to $1400/night for a room that was $120 a week earlier.

This being said, current prices for 5-star in downtown Sydney seem on on the lower side of the spectrum but not in "bargain" territory. Most quote around US$150/night for starters, but once you are in a nicer room plus taxes+fees it'll probably end up in the US$200-$250 range. That feels "normal" for low-season.

FWIW: may favorite place to stay in Sydney is an ocean front room in the Crown Plaza at Coogee Beach: spectacular views from the balcony. However, it's certainly not a bargain at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Some. I've promoted some on [beatthatflight.com.au](https://www.beatthatflight.com.au) (my site) and on the FB page when applicable (I usually tend to focus on flights but there have been some amazing ones).

For example, the [5-Star Hyatt Regency Sydney from $179 for a King Room](https://www.ozbargain.com.au/node/536851), with Free Cancellation at New Years and on weekends at Christmas period, was/is a great price.